# Windows 2003 X64 Std page file usage

Tags: windows-server-2003

Just trying to understand why I'm seeing what I'm seeing on this system.  Pagefile performance counters are telling me i'm @ about 1.5% used with my page file, settings for the file are 2GB-4GB, but task manager was showing 13GB usage:
[image]

Oddly enough, it just sunk down:
[image]

This machine has IBM DB2 9.5 workgroup edition running on it.  Thoughts???  Actually, just learned the developer had just stopped DB2, hence the huge drop, just not understand the difference in the PF usage in task manager vs perf counters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're just getting confused with terminology used in that dialog.

In the Windows Task manager the PF Usage and Page File Usage History includes all the paging space that the system has.  So anywhere that it can store a page...which includes physical memory and the page file (swap).

Since this machine has 20GB of real ram from the looks of the image it's possible to be using 13GB of Pages without swapping.

Comment: ahhhh, your correct, i was a bit confused obviously.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has a long history of using confusing and inconsistent labels in Task Manager and "PF Usage" is one of the worst. This is actually the Commit Charge and has nothing to do with actual pagefile usage, which from a performance standpoint isn't really that important. This is more like potential pagefile usage. If everything that is in RAM that could be paged to the pagefile actually was, this is the size that would be required. Calling this "PF Usage" has caused enormous confusion, even among experts.